# Sessions JSP button click

Tags: html, jsp, button

Hi I want to do a JSP program where there is a number displayed and a button. When the user clicks this button the number above it increments. I want to include sessions in this program.

What I have done is this:

This is the form in html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<%! public void displayNum(){ %>
Number: <%=session.getAttribute("Counter") %>
<%! } %>

<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="getcount.jsp"> 
<button TYPE="button" ONCLICK= "displayNum()">Add 1</button>
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is myJSP file:

```
<% 
     AddCount addCount = new AddCount();
     addCount.setCounter(addCount.addCounter(addCount.getCounter()));
     int counter = addCount.getCounter();

     session.setAttribute("Counter", counter);
%>
```

where AddCount is a java class with a variable counter, setter and getter and a function to increase the counter - addCount(num);  all I'm getting when running the file is a button without any text in it :/

I've been trying over and over again. Can someone help me please?

Thankss!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding java code in html, which is not possible.

Second thing even if you are having a static int counter in AddCount it wont work as many user s may use this page and expect only one increment for their each click.

So what you should do is write a jsp file like this index.jsp

```
<%Integer counter = (Integer)request.getSession().getAttribute("counter")
  if(counter==null) {counter=0;}
  counter ++;
  request.getSession().setAttribute("counter",counter);

 %>
 <div>counter=<%=counter%></div><br>
 <a href="index.jsp">+1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

function displayNum()
{

<% 
     AddCount addCount = new AddCount();
     addCount.setCounter(addCount.addCounter(addCount.getCounter()));
     int counter = addCount.getCounter();

     session.setAttribute("Counter", counter);
%>

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<%=session.getAttribute("Counter")%>";
}

<p id="demo"> {number will be displayed here} </p>
<button TYPE="button" ONCLICK= "displayNum()">Add 1</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this.. but when I run it I'm only getting Number 1 and no button!!! Thanks for helping btw

Comment: Try using jQuery ajax, I have added to the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <title>My Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $("#div1").load("increament.jsp");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="div1"> {number will be displayed here} </div>
    <button>Add 1</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and increament.jsp file :

```
<%
    int count;
    if (session.getAttribute("Counter") == null) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count = (Integer) session.getAttribute("Counter");
        count++;
    }
    session.setAttribute("Counter", count);
    out.println(session.getAttribute("Counter"));
 %>
```